identification of adjunction space with disjoint union
I am asking for someone to verify the below.
Notation: I define the disjoint union as
$A \sqcup B = \{(a, 0)~|~a \in A\} \cup \{(b, 1)~|~b \in B\}$.
Let $X, Y$ be topological spaces, $A \subset Y$ a subspace, and $f: A \to X$ a continuous map. Then we define the adjunction space as
$X \cup_f Y = (X \sqcup Y)/\sim$, where $\sim$ is the equivalence relation generated by $a \sim f(a)$ for all $a \in A$.
The wikipedia page claims that:

As a set, $X \cup_f Y$ consists of the disjoint union of $X$ and $(Y - A)$.

Presumably this is referring to some canonical identification as they can't be equal as sets. I am thinking maybe the mapping $i: X \sqcup (Y - A) \to X \cup_f Y$ that sends $p \mapsto [p]$ is a bijection.
Surjectivity is clear. Suppose $[p] \in X \cup_f Y$, where $p \in X \sqcup Y$. In the case that $p = (x, 0)$ for some $x \in X$, of course $(x, 0) \in X \sqcup (Y-A)$ so $i(p) = [p]$. If instead $p = (y, 1)$ for some $y \in Y$, then if $y \in (Y - A)$ we just have $i(p) = p$, and if instead $y \in A$ we would have $(y, 1) \sim (f(y), 0)$ so $i((f(y), 0)) = [p]$.
Injectivity follows from the following facts: the equivalence class $[(y, 1)]$ for $y \in (Y - A)$ is a singleton, and the equivalence class $[(x, 0)]$ for $x \in X$ consists of only $(x, 0)$ and potentially elements of the form $(y, 1)$ for $y \in A$ (importantly $(x, 0) \sim (y, 1)$ never holds when $y \in (Y - A)$).

Yes, this is all correct. Do you have any specific doubts regarding any part of this?

@DavidGao No I just wanted assurance. Thank you!
